# What is the best (quickest) way to test changes to a CordaApp?

Tags: corda

I wonder how to achieve the shortest feedback cycle for CordApp changes. Right now it takes around 2 minutes for each change when I do:
gradle clean build deployNoded
and
runnodes
again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making contract changes, you should use Corda's contract testing framework. Here's an example from the [IOU CorDapp's contract tests](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/contract/IOUContractTests.kt):

```
@Test
fun `transaction must include Create command`() {
    ledgerServices.ledger {
        transaction {
            output(IOU_CONTRACT_ID, IOUState(1, miniCorp.party, megaCorp.party))
            fails()
            command(listOf(megaCorp.publicKey, miniCorp.publicKey), IOUContract.Commands.Create())
            verifies()
        }
    }
}
```

If you're making other CorDapp changes, you should use Corda's flow testing framework. Here's an example from the [IOU CorDapp's flow tests](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/flow/IOUFlowTests.kt):

```
@Test
fun `flow records the correct IOU in both parties' vaults`() {
    val iouValue = 1
    val flow = ExampleFlow.Initiator(1, b.info.singleIdentity())
    val future = a.startFlow(flow)
    network.runNetwork()
    future.getOrThrow()

    // We check the recorded IOU in both vaults.
    for (node in listOf(a, b)) {
        node.transaction {
            val ious = node.services.vaultService.queryBy<IOUState>().states
            assertEquals(1, ious.size)
            val recordedState = ious.single().state.data
            assertEquals(recordedState.value, iouValue)
            assertEquals(recordedState.lender, a.info.singleIdentity())
            assertEquals(recordedState.borrower, b.info.singleIdentity())
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more details here: https://docs.corda.net/api-testing.html#contract-testing.